Ubuntu Pro Enabling anbox-cloud-appliance
Image1 iI am enabling the anbox-cloud on my machine which is Ubuntu 22.04. but when I hit the command:
sudo anbox-cloud-appliance init

it fails with the following error:
Error: running on desktop is not supported

image2
My device is Asus Vivobook without graphic.

"My device is Asus Vivobook without graphic" Your image shows an installed windowing system, suggesting that you installed Ubuntu Desktop. anbox-cloud-appliance seems to be looking for an install of Ubuntu Server, which is different.

how can i proceed the installation of anbox-cloud-appliance
